# Spring Data Rest - customize endpoint name

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-rest

By default, Spring data REST use camelCase for endpoint names.

For example, if the repository is

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "users", path = "users")
public interface UserRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<User, Integer> {

    List<User> findByUsername(@Param("username") String username);

}
```

Then the endpoint is `http://localhost:8080/users/search/findByUsername?username=test`

How can I customize the endpoint so it use snake_case, became like this: `http://localhost:8080/users/search/find_by_username?username=test`

Or even different method name

- change `find_by_username` : `http://localhost:8080/users/search/by_username?username=test`
- (stripping the `find_by_username`): `http://localhost:8080/users/search?username=test`

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `@RestResource` annotation also gives us the ability to customize the URL path mapped to a repository method and the link id in the JSON returned by the HATEOAS resource discovery.

To do that, we use the optional parameters of the annotation:

- **path** for the URL path
- **rel** for the link id

By executing a cUrl to `http://localhost:8080/users/search/`, we can now see our new method listed with other resources:

```
{
  "_links": {
    "findByUsername": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/users/search/findByUsername{?username}"
    },
    "self": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/users/search/"
    }
  }
}
```

So to customize the rest url endpoint, we can simply add the `@RestResource` annotation:

```
@RestResource(path = "byUsername", rel = "customFindMethod")
 List<User> findByUsername(@Param("username") String username);
```

If we do the resource discovery again, the resulting JSON will confirm our changes:

```
{
  "_links": {
    "customFindMethod": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/users/search/byUsername{?username}",
      "templated": true
    },
    "self": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/users/search/"
    }
  }
}
```

For more details you can check [her](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-rest-customize-http-endpoints)